# mongo db lookup with list of IDs and count a certain field and add it to the original document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two different collection. following are -

Collection A (which consist a list of pipeline ID):

```
    {
        "_id" : "1c0c97b6-8313-4ed2-8fd3-abbb82fe5e72",
        "minToClose" : 1,
        
        "pipelines" : ["c6ce1f81-b109-4f70-a9b7-53322c1b1a93","f9a0eb75-b56e-4819-a836-e5ae9abb43cd","b0c5d1dd-6af0-40d0-a0c9-0e659d62b0fa" ],
        "extra" : {
            "autoPair" : "2022-06-02T09:36:15.317Z"
        },
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-06-02T09:36:15.266Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-06-02T09:36:15.266Z"),
    },{
        "_id" : "26965615-979b-49dc-99ef-47be25c2d4c2",
        "minToClose" : 3,
        "pipelines" : ["c6ce1f81-b109-4f70-a9b7-53322c1b1a93","f9a0eb75-b56e-4819-a836-e5ae9abb43cd", "50d577ec-d4bc-4417-8d9c-db1d4795d29b","264f4f2c-baff-443f-82dc-cc462aa67bd6","b0c5d1dd-6af0-40d0-a0c9-0e659d62b0fa"   ],
        "extra" : {
            "autoPair" : "2022-06-02T09:36:15.317Z"
        },
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-06-02T09:36:15.266Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-06-02T09:36:15.266Z"),
    }
```

now we have pipeline collection :

```
    {
    "_id" : "c6ce1f81-b109-4f70-a9b7-53322c1b1a93",
    "status" : "OPEN",
    "isAbandoned" : false,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-05-27T16:13:22.160Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-05-27T16:13:45.779Z")
     },{
    "_id" : "f9a0eb75-b56e-4819-a836-e5ae9abb43cd",
    "status" : "CLOSE",
    "isAbandoned" : false,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-05-27T16:13:22.160Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-05-27T16:13:45.779Z")
     },
{
    "_id" : "b0c5d1dd-6af0-40d0-a0c9-0e659d62b0fa",
    "status" : "CLOSE",
    "isAbandoned" : false,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-05-27T16:13:22.160Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-05-27T16:13:45.779Z")
     },{
    "_id" : "50d577ec-d4bc-4417-8d9c-db1d4795d29b",
    "status" : "CANCEL",
    "isAbandoned" : false,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-05-27T16:13:22.160Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-05-27T16:13:45.779Z")
     },{
    "_id" : "264f4f2c-baff-443f-82dc-cc462aa67bd6",
    "status" : "OPEN",
    "isAbandoned" : false,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-05-27T16:13:22.160Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-05-27T16:13:45.779Z")
     }
```

I want to count the number of Close+cancel and place it in the extra map of collection A . Like the below code :

```
{
        "_id" : "1c0c97b6-8313-4ed2-8fd3-abbb82fe5e72",
        "minToClose" : 1,
        
        "pipelines" : ["c6ce1f81-b109-4f70-a9b7-53322c1b1a93","f9a0eb75-b56e-4819-a836-e5ae9abb43cd","b0c5d1dd-6af0-40d0-a0c9-0e659d62b0fa" ],
        "extra" : {
            "autoPair" : "2022-06-02T09:36:15.317Z",
            "totalClosedandCanceledCount" :  2
        },
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-06-02T09:36:15.266Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-06-02T09:36:15.266Z"),
    },{
        "_id" : "26965615-979b-49dc-99ef-47be25c2d4c2",
        "minToClose" : 3,
        "pipelines" : ["c6ce1f81-b109-4f70-a9b7-53322c1b1a93","f9a0eb75-b56e-4819-a836-e5ae9abb43cd", "50d577ec-d4bc-4417-8d9c-db1d4795d29b","264f4f2c-baff-443f-82dc-cc462aa67bd6","b0c5d1dd-6af0-40d0-a0c9-0e659d62b0fa"   ],
        "extra" : {
            "autoPair" : "2022-06-02T09:36:15.317Z",
            "totalClosedandCanceledCount" :  3
        },
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-06-02T09:36:15.266Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-06-02T09:36:15.266Z"),
    }
```

I tried to write the mongo aggregation. but failed to Iterate the list.Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an attempt at your aggregation needs...

### Aggregation

```
db.a.aggregate([
    { $addFields: { pipelinesOriginal: "$pipelines" } }, 
    { $unwind: "$pipelines" },
    {
        $lookup:
        {
            from: "pipeline",
            localField: "pipelines",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "lookupValues"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$lookupValues"
    },
    {
        $match: { "lookupValues.status": { $in: [ "CLOSE", "CANCEL" ] } }
    },
    {
        $group:
        {
            _id: "$_id",
            minToClose: { $first: "$minToClose" },
            pipelines: { $first: "$pipelinesOriginal" },
            extra: { $first: "$extra" },
            createdAt: { $first: "$createdAt" },
            updatedAt: { $first: "$updatedAt" },
            count: { $sum: 1}            
        }
    },
    { $addFields: { "extra.totalClosedandCanceledCount": { "$toInt": "$count" } } },
    { $project: { "count": 0 } }
]).pretty()
```

### Results

```
{
        "_id" : "26965615-979b-49dc-99ef-47be25c2d4c2",
        "minToClose" : 3,
        "pipelines" : [
                "c6ce1f81-b109-4f70-a9b7-53322c1b1a93",
                "f9a0eb75-b56e-4819-a836-e5ae9abb43cd",
                "50d577ec-d4bc-4417-8d9c-db1d4795d29b",
                "264f4f2c-baff-443f-82dc-cc462aa67bd6",
                "b0c5d1dd-6af0-40d0-a0c9-0e659d62b0fa"
        ],
        "extra" : {
                "autoPair" : "2022-06-02T09:36:15.317Z",
                "totalClosedandCanceledCount" : 3
        },
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-06-02T09:36:15.266Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-06-02T09:36:15.266Z")
}
{
        "_id" : "1c0c97b6-8313-4ed2-8fd3-abbb82fe5e72",
        "minToClose" : 1,
        "pipelines" : [
                "c6ce1f81-b109-4f70-a9b7-53322c1b1a93",
                "f9a0eb75-b56e-4819-a836-e5ae9abb43cd",
                "b0c5d1dd-6af0-40d0-a0c9-0e659d62b0fa"
        ],
        "extra" : {
                "autoPair" : "2022-06-02T09:36:15.317Z",
                "totalClosedandCanceledCount" : 2
        },
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-06-02T09:36:15.266Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-06-02T09:36:15.266Z")
}
```

### Explanation

**Stage 1 -** `{ $addFields: { pipelinesOriginal: "$pipelines" } }`

Need to retain the array of pipeline key values for final output.  Stage 2 will modify the document values as needed for parsing...

**Stage 2 -** `{ $unwind: "$pipelines" }`

The third stage needs the foreign keys on a separate record.  For this reason, break them out using $unwind.

**Stage 3 -** `{ $lookup: { from: "pipeline", localField: "pipelines", foreignField: "_id", as: "lookupValues" } }`

Get details from a related table/collection.  This puts the found results into an array in each related document called `lookupValues`.

**Stage 4 -**  `{ $unwind: "$lookupValues" }`

For stage 6 grouping and aggregate functions we need a record per found lookup record.  For this reason, unwind the found values in the array `lookupValues`.

**Stage 5 -** `{ $match: { "lookupValues.status": { $in: [ "CLOSE", "CANCEL" ] } } }`

Only consider status values of `CLOSE`, or `CANCEL` for counting.

**Stage 6 -** `$group` (not putting the entire operator here -too long)

Basically, group by the original _id field value and count each record matched in stage 5.  Use the $first operator to retain the other fields.  Notice we put back the original pipeline array in its original form here.

**Stage 7 -** `{ $addFields: { "extra.totalClosedandCanceledCount": "$count" } }`

Move the count to the desired area of the document.  Here we create and embed a new field `totalClosedandCanceledCount` under the existing field `extra`.

**Stage 8 -** `{ $project: { "count": 0 } }`

Remove the field `count` by using a projection.  We have already copied this field to the desired location in `extra.totalClosedandCanceledCount` and we no longer need the field `count`.

### Conclusion

There is no sorting predicate and no sort was specified.

### Appendix

**Test Data**

```
db.a.insertMany([{
        "_id" : "1c0c97b6-8313-4ed2-8fd3-abbb82fe5e72",
        "minToClose" : 1,
        "pipelines" : [
                "c6ce1f81-b109-4f70-a9b7-53322c1b1a93",
                "f9a0eb75-b56e-4819-a836-e5ae9abb43cd",
                "b0c5d1dd-6af0-40d0-a0c9-0e659d62b0fa"
        ],
        "extra" : {
                "autoPair" : "2022-06-02T09:36:15.317Z"
        },
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-06-02T09:36:15.266Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-06-02T09:36:15.266Z")
},
{
        "_id" : "26965615-979b-49dc-99ef-47be25c2d4c2",
        "minToClose" : 3,
        "pipelines" : [
                "c6ce1f81-b109-4f70-a9b7-53322c1b1a93",
                "f9a0eb75-b56e-4819-a836-e5ae9abb43cd",
                "50d577ec-d4bc-4417-8d9c-db1d4795d29b",
                "264f4f2c-baff-443f-82dc-cc462aa67bd6",
                "b0c5d1dd-6af0-40d0-a0c9-0e659d62b0fa"
        ],
        "extra" : {
                "autoPair" : "2022-06-02T09:36:15.317Z"
        },
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-06-02T09:36:15.266Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-06-02T09:36:15.266Z")
}])


db.pipeline.insertMany([{
        "_id" : "c6ce1f81-b109-4f70-a9b7-53322c1b1a93",
        "status" : "OPEN",
        "isAbandoned" : false,
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-05-27T16:13:22.160Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-05-27T16:13:45.779Z")
},
{
        "_id" : "f9a0eb75-b56e-4819-a836-e5ae9abb43cd",
        "status" : "CLOSE",
        "isAbandoned" : false,
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-05-27T16:13:22.160Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-05-27T16:13:45.779Z")
},
{
        "_id" : "b0c5d1dd-6af0-40d0-a0c9-0e659d62b0fa",
        "status" : "CLOSE",
        "isAbandoned" : false,
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-05-27T16:13:22.160Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-05-27T16:13:45.779Z")
},
{
        "_id" : "50d577ec-d4bc-4417-8d9c-db1d4795d29b",
        "status" : "CANCEL",
        "isAbandoned" : false,
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-05-27T16:13:22.160Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-05-27T16:13:45.779Z")
},
{
        "_id" : "264f4f2c-baff-443f-82dc-cc462aa67bd6",
        "status" : "OPEN",
        "isAbandoned" : false,
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-05-27T16:13:22.160Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-05-27T16:13:45.779Z")
}])
```

### EDIT

Per requirements clarification, need to have a count of zero for records in collection 'a' where no related records are closed or cancelled.

**TEST RECORDS**

```
db.a.drop();
db.a.insertMany([{
        "_id" : "1c0c97b6-8313-4ed2-8fd3-abbb82fe5e72",
        "minToClose" : 1,
        "pipelines" : [
                "c6ce1f81-b109-4f70-a9b7-53322c1b1a93",
                "f9a0eb75-b56e-4819-a836-e5ae9abb43cd",
                "b0c5d1dd-6af0-40d0-a0c9-0e659d62b0fa"
        ],
        "extra" : {
                "autoPair" : "2022-06-02T09:36:15.317Z"
        },
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-06-02T09:36:15.266Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-06-02T09:36:15.266Z")
},
{
        "_id" : "26965615-979b-49dc-99ef-47be25c2d4c2",
        "minToClose" : 3,
        "pipelines" : [
                "c6ce1f81-b109-4f70-a9b7-53322c1b1a93",
                "f9a0eb75-b56e-4819-a836-e5ae9abb43cd",
                "50d577ec-d4bc-4417-8d9c-db1d4795d29b",
                "264f4f2c-baff-443f-82dc-cc462aa67bd6",
                "b0c5d1dd-6af0-40d0-a0c9-0e659d62b0fa"
        ],
        "extra" : {
                "autoPair" : "2022-06-02T09:36:15.317Z"
        },
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-06-02T09:36:15.266Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-06-02T09:36:15.266Z")
},
{
        "_id" : "d5c54949-93b1-4a38-a2ed-067803448b8d",
        "minToClose" : 1,
        "pipelines" : [
                "b1cad01b-b1c7-46d5-8eef-00fe4c3eb68b",
                "a22d0ba6-8494-437d-ac4e-d470be850684",
                "bf10be9d-3214-4c64-9bc9-5e9d4beea746"
        ],
        "extra" : {
                "autoPair" : "2022-06-01T09:36:15.317Z"
        },
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-06-01T09:36:15.266Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-06-01T09:36:15.266Z")
}])








db.pipeline.drop()
db.pipeline.insertMany([{
        "_id" : "c6ce1f81-b109-4f70-a9b7-53322c1b1a93",
        "status" : "OPEN",
        "isAbandoned" : false,
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-05-27T16:13:22.160Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-05-27T16:13:45.779Z")
},
{
        "_id" : "f9a0eb75-b56e-4819-a836-e5ae9abb43cd",
        "status" : "CLOSE",
        "isAbandoned" : false,
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-05-27T16:13:22.160Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-05-27T16:13:45.779Z")
},
{
        "_id" : "b0c5d1dd-6af0-40d0-a0c9-0e659d62b0fa",
        "status" : "CLOSE",
        "isAbandoned" : false,
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-05-27T16:13:22.160Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-05-27T16:13:45.779Z")
},
{
        "_id" : "50d577ec-d4bc-4417-8d9c-db1d4795d29b",
        "status" : "CANCEL",
        "isAbandoned" : false,
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-05-27T16:13:22.160Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-05-27T16:13:45.779Z")
},
{
        "_id" : "264f4f2c-baff-443f-82dc-cc462aa67bd6",
        "status" : "OPEN",
        "isAbandoned" : false,
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-05-27T16:13:22.160Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-05-27T16:13:45.779Z")
},
{
        "_id" : "b1cad01b-b1c7-46d5-8eef-00fe4c3eb68b",
        "status" : "OPEN",
        "isAbandoned" : false,
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-05-27T16:13:22.160Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-05-27T16:13:45.779Z")
},
{
        "_id" : "a22d0ba6-8494-437d-ac4e-d470be850684",
        "status" : "OPEN",
        "isAbandoned" : false,
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-05-27T16:13:22.160Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-05-27T16:13:45.779Z")
},
{
        "_id" : "bf10be9d-3214-4c64-9bc9-5e9d4beea746",
        "status" : "OPEN",
        "isAbandoned" : false,
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-05-27T16:13:22.160Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-05-27T16:13:45.779Z")
}])
```

**Aggregation**

```
db.a.aggregate([
    { $addFields: { pipelinesOriginal: "$pipelines" } }, 
    { $unwind: "$pipelines" },
    {
        $lookup:
        {
            from: "pipeline",
            localField: "pipelines",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "lookupValues"
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$lookupValues" },
    {
        $project:
        {
            _id: 1,
            minToClose: 1,
            pipelines: "$pipelinesOriginal",
            extra: 1,
            createdAt: 1,
            updatedAt: 1,
            lookupValues: 1,
            closedFlag:
            {
                $switch:
                {
                    branches:
                    [
                        { "case": { $eq: [ "$lookupValues.status", "CLOSE" ] }, then: 1 },
                        { "case": { $eq: [ "$lookupValues.status", "CANCEL" ] }, then: 1 }
                    ],
                    default: 0
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group:
        {
            _id: "$_id",
            minToClose: { $first: "$minToClose" },
            pipelines: { $first: "$pipelines" },
            extra: { $first: "$extra" },
            createdAt: { $first: "$createdAt" },
            updatedAt: { $first: "$updatedAt" },
            count: { $sum: "$closedFlag"} 
        }
    },
    { $addFields: { "extra.totalClosedandCanceledCount": { "$toInt": "$count" } } },
    { $project: { "count": 0 } }
]).pretty()
```

**Results**

```
{
        "_id" : "d5c54949-93b1-4a38-a2ed-067803448b8d",
        "minToClose" : 1,
        "pipelines" : [
                "b1cad01b-b1c7-46d5-8eef-00fe4c3eb68b",
                "a22d0ba6-8494-437d-ac4e-d470be850684",
                "bf10be9d-3214-4c64-9bc9-5e9d4beea746"
        ],
        "extra" : {
                "autoPair" : "2022-06-01T09:36:15.317Z",
                "totalClosedandCanceledCount" : 0
        },
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-06-01T09:36:15.266Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-06-01T09:36:15.266Z")
}
{
        "_id" : "26965615-979b-49dc-99ef-47be25c2d4c2",
        "minToClose" : 3,
        "pipelines" : [
                "c6ce1f81-b109-4f70-a9b7-53322c1b1a93",
                "f9a0eb75-b56e-4819-a836-e5ae9abb43cd",
                "50d577ec-d4bc-4417-8d9c-db1d4795d29b",
                "264f4f2c-baff-443f-82dc-cc462aa67bd6",
                "b0c5d1dd-6af0-40d0-a0c9-0e659d62b0fa"
        ],
        "extra" : {
                "autoPair" : "2022-06-02T09:36:15.317Z",
                "totalClosedandCanceledCount" : 3
        },
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-06-02T09:36:15.266Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-06-02T09:36:15.266Z")
}
{
        "_id" : "1c0c97b6-8313-4ed2-8fd3-abbb82fe5e72",
        "minToClose" : 1,
        "pipelines" : [
                "c6ce1f81-b109-4f70-a9b7-53322c1b1a93",
                "f9a0eb75-b56e-4819-a836-e5ae9abb43cd",
                "b0c5d1dd-6af0-40d0-a0c9-0e659d62b0fa"
        ],
        "extra" : {
                "autoPair" : "2022-06-02T09:36:15.317Z",
                "totalClosedandCanceledCount" : 2
        },
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-06-02T09:36:15.266Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-06-02T09:36:15.266Z")
}
```

Comment: Bravo! It worked for me. However It is giving me in float. anyway we can put int? 
----------this is what I am getting -> 
"extra" : {
        "autoPair" : "2022-06-02T09:36:15.317Z",
        "totalClosedandCanceledCount" : 1.0
    }

Comment: Hi @Nillogical.  Normally numeric value datatypes are an application implementation detail.  My mongoshell test is not showing them as a floating point.  I assume you are using mongosh as your mongoshell?  At any rate, I wrapped the field with a `$toInt`.  Please see my updates to my post and try again...

Comment: yes $toInt worked for me @barrypicker. one observation on this. this query is fetching all the docs where pipeline statuses are "CLOSE" or "CANCEL". but It is not fetching "OPEN". Basically totalClosedandCanceledCount was used to count the number of close and cancelled. but it will not ignore OPEN status

Comment: in this case if a doc has OPEN status pipeline, the query is ignoring those in result

Comment: @Nillogical, Sorry, I think I misunderstand the requirements.  Did you want to include 'OPEN'?  Your original post expected results do not include any 'OPEN' records...

Comment: yes I want all the docs from collection A. however in "extra" I want the close /cancel count only

Comment: Hi @Nillogical, I have edited my answer - see the very bottom, labeled 'EDIT'.  The second aggregation is included at the bottom...  Including the non-closed and non-cancelled required the use of the $switch operator.

Comment: thank you It worked for me. Only 1 change I made - Added "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true in the unwind section in case we have zero pipelines in the list.